# Html Form within html table using jquery Yadis/freeze-table

Tags: html, jquery, laravel, plugins

I have in my laravel project a form in which there is a table whose cells contain select type inputs. the values ​​of the lists of these selects are taken from the database.
I have long looked for a way to freeze the headers and the first column of the table so that when pointing we do not lose sight of the length of the table because we had to scroll and I found a javascript library that I use: yadis/freeze-table. The problem is that when I use this library and I choose different values ​​in my selects for each field that my form submits, the values ​​sent are the default values ​​that are on the selects but when I remove this library and I do the same operation, the values ​​change. I want to know how I can do it while using the library. THANKS

there is my code :

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('roulements.store') }}" id="form-create">
     @csrf
     <div class="table-responsive table-scrollable" style="color: #2d2b2b;">
         <input type="hidden" name="mensualite_id" id="mensualite_id" value="{{ $mensualite->id }}">
         <input type="hidden" name="service_id" id="service_id" value="{{ $service->id }}">
         <table class="table table-bordered">
             <thead>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Jour</td>
                       @foreach($titres as $titre)
                       <td style="writing-mode: vertical-rl;transform: rotate(180deg)">
                           {{ $titre['nom_jour'] }}
                       </td>
                       @endforeach
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Date</td>
                       @foreach($titres as $titre)
                       <td>
                           {{ $titre['no_jour'] }}
                       </td>
                       @endforeach
                  </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
               @php $i = 1 @endphp
               @foreach($agents as $agent)
               <tr>
                  <input type="hidden" name="agent_id_{{$i}}" value="{{ $agent->id }}">
                  <td width="60%">{{ $agent->nom_agent }} {{ $agent->postnom_agent }} {{ $agent->prenom_agent }}</td>
                       @php $j = 1 @endphp
                       @foreach($titres as $titre)
                           <input type="hidden" name="date_roulement_{{ $j }}" value="{{ $titre['date'] }}">
                           <td  style="text-align: center">
                                <select name="{{ $i }}{{ $j }}" class="form-control-sm">
                                      @foreach($etiquettes as $etiquette)
                                           <option value="{{ $etiquette->id }}">{{ $etiquette->nom_etiquette }}</option>
                                      @endforeach
                                </select>
                           </td>
                           @php $j += 1 @endphp
                       @endforeach
                       </tr>

                       @php $i += 1 @endphp
             @endforeach
             <input type="hidden" name="i" value="{{ $i }}">
             <input type="hidden" name="j" value="{{ $j }}">
       </tbody>
</table>
</div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
         {!! $tabButtons['btnValider'] !!}
    </div>
</form>
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".table-scrollable").freezeTable({
                    'shadow': true,
                    'scrollBar': true
                });
    });
```

Here is the result of the html code :
[Image describing html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG7HU.png)

Here is the form with choosen select :
[while sending form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn4vT.png)

Here is the result on the server when i send form while using the library :
[while using plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1lUV.png)

Here is the difference of result on the server when i send form when not using the library :
[after removing the plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y5Aj.png)

Notice that my wish is to use the plugins but also to have a good result when choosing in my select, how to achieve this? I need your opinion. Thanks in advance